# Mixing Spring Social versions for different providers

Tags: spring-social, spring-social-facebook, spring-social-linkedin

In the same program, I am using Spring-social facebook and Spring Social linkedIn.
I can not however make them both work on the same release environment :

Facebook works fine with the following versions flavour :

```
    <org.springframework.social-version>1.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.social-version>
    <org.springframework.social.facebook-version>1.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.social.facebook-version>
```

The only way I have managed to have linked in work properly and not return display "unexepcted error has occured" on the linked in site connection page is with :

```
    <org.springframework.social-version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</org.springframework.social-version>
    <org.springframework.social.linkedin-version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</org.springframework.social.linkedin-version>
```

do any of you know about a spring social version that would properly work with both?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

In my application I have used facebook and twitter combined with the version 1.1.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT

```
<org.springframework.social-version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</org.springframework.social-version>
<org.springframework.social.facebook-version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</org.springframework.social.facebook-version>
<org.springframework.social.twitter-version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</org.springframework.social.twitter-version>
```

I am not sure if it will work with linkedin also or not. Try it may it work.

Comment: Your answer was helpful to look around which made me realize the problem is not due to this pom difference. I will be reposting another question. On the subject